# Dagger2 is not generating classes in android

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using `Dagger2` in my android application, I have two component in my application. First is global for entire application and second is specific to activity instance.

**NetComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(AuthenticationActivity authenticationActivity);

    void inject(PaymentActivity paymentActivity);
}
```

**ValidationComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ValidatorModule.class})
public interface ValidationComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);
}
```

**AppModule.java**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

**NetModule.java**

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideOkHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                //.addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
        return okHttpClient;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("authRetrofit")
    Retrofit provideAuthRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(PAYMENT_SERVICE)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("paymentRetrofit")
    Retrofit providePaymentRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(LOGIN_SERVICE)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

**ValidatorModule.java**

```
@Module
public class ValidatorModule {

    private final Activity activity;


    public ValidatorModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator providesValidator() {
        return new com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator(activity);
    }
}
```

**AppApplication.java**

```
public class AppApplication extends Application {

    private NetComponent mNetComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public NetComponent getmNetComponent() {
        return mNetComponent;
    }

}
```

**AuthenticationActivity.java**

```
public class AuthenticationActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Validator.ValidationListener {

    @Inject
    Validator validator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....

        ((AppApplication) getApplication()).getmNetComponent().inject(this);

        ValidationComponent validationComponent = DaggerValidationComponent.builder()
                .validatorModule(getValidatorModule())
                .build();

        validationComponent.inject(this);

        ...

        // apply click and validation listeners
        validator.setValidationListener(this);
    }
}   

protected ValidatorModule getValidatorModule() {
    return new ValidatorModule(this);
}
```

It is generating `ValidationComponent` but not `DaggerNetComponent`

[image]

Above are my module, components of my application. When I am compiling and building a application then I am getting below errors -

**Error**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\AppApplication.java
Error:(24, 48) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNetComponent
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\login\AuthenticationActivity.java
Error:(35, 48) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerValidationComponent
Error:(39, 43) error: package com.icici.iciciappathon.databinding does not exist
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\checkout\PaymentActivity.java
Error:(28, 43) error: package com.icici.iciciappathon.databinding does not exist
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\dashboard\DashboardActivity.java
Error:(32, 43) error: package com.icici.iciciappathon.databinding does not exist
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\shopping\ScanBarcodeActivity.java
Error:(41, 43) error: package com.icici.iciciappathon.databinding does not exist
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\ui\GetStartedActivity.java
Error:(27, 43) error: package com.icici.iciciappathon.databinding does not exist
C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\dagger\component\NetComponent.java
Error:(34, 10) error: com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
com.icici.iciciappathon.login.AuthenticationActivity.validator
[injected field of type: com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator validator]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 11.373 secs
Information:9 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: This inject seems suspicious to me: `validationComponent.inject(this);` Did you accidentally created cycled dependency with it?

Comment: @AntonMalmygin Nope. How it is cycled dependency. If you see my edited question. my project structure, It is generating `ValidationComponent` but not `DaggerNetComponent` this is weird isn't ?

Comment: Can you verify you have imported `com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator` in your activity?

Comment: @azizbekian Yup.

Comment: Can you post a basic project with that setup?

Comment: @azizbekian I think I posted sufficient code, it is large application, bit difficult to share code

Comment: I think if you comment out `((AppApplication) getApplication()).getmNetComponent().inject(this);` this line, you won't see that exception happening.

Comment: Then how dagger will initialize netcomponent dependency ?

Comment: @azizbekian I commented that line, no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general statement here is that Dagger doesn't generate classes when it encounters an error, usually when you're doing something impossible in your binding graph. That's the case here.

> C:\Users\xyz\AndroidStudioProjects\ICICIAppathon\app\src\main\java\com\icici\iciciappathon\dagger\component\NetComponent.java
> Error:(34, 10) error: com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
> com.icici.iciciappathon.login.AuthenticationActivity.validator
> [injected field of type: com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator validator]

I agree with [azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43942293/1426891) that the problem is that you are trying to inject the Validator from within AuthenticationActivity, and telling NetComponent to try to do so without instructing it how to do so (in ValidationModule).

In the code you've posted, there isn't a reason for NetComponent to inject AuthenticationActivity; there's nothing for it to provide. So you can delete these two lines and be done:

```
// In NetComponent
void inject(AuthenticationActivity authenticationActivity);

// In AuthenticationActivity
((AppApplication) getApplication()).getmNetComponent().inject(this);
```

However, it's also possible that you've simply not shown us the NetComponent dependencies you need in AuthenticationActivity. In that case, you're going to need to combine the object graphs, either through subcomponents or component dependencies. *You'll still need to delete the two lines listed above*, because under no circumstance does NetComponent have the dependencies it needs to inject AuthenticationActivity.

#### Subcomponents

To do so with [subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html), simply make a builder on NetComponent through which you get your ValidationActivity. You're welcome to provide a scope, but you don't necessarily need one, and I think it might be confusing to add that into the mix. At that point, your ValidationComponent will have access to all the bindings in your NetComponent AND all of the bindings listed in ValidationComponent. This is effectively identical to azizbekian's answer, though notably this is through subcomponents, not component dependencies. I'll talk about component dependencies in a moment.

```
// After removing the inject(AuthenticationActivity) call, add this to NetComponent
ValidatorComponent validatorComponent(ValidatorModule validatorModule);

// And call the implementation from AuthenticationActivity
((AppApplication) getApplication()).getmNetComponent()
    .validatorModule(new ValidatorModule(this))
    .inject();
```

You'll also need to switch `ValidationComponent` from `@Component` to `@Subcomponent`, and remove the `@Singleton` instance (which makes sense because you're creating a new one for every AuthenticationActivity instance Android creates.

Effectively, this turns NetComponent into a *factory* for ValidationComponent instances. Dagger generates the code for both at once, so ValidationComponent can access anything it needs from NetComponent automatically. However, this way it is impossible to generate code for each one separately, or to get a ValidationComponent without a NetComponent instance (except through including it in another component).

#### Component dependencies

[Component dependencies](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies) work a little bit differently. They're freestanding components, so they can be generated separately and independently. Instead, you can pass in an interface (often but not necessarily another Dagger component like NetComponent), and every single no-argument method becomes an automatic provider into the other graph. This means, for example, that you could list specific dependencies available to ValidationComponent from NetComponent, add a `dependencies={NetComponent.class}` to your ValidationComponent definition, and then change your DaggerValidationComponent builder to call `.netComponent(((AppApplication getApplication()).getmNetComponent())` to hook the exact instances up. (Similarly, you could do so with any implementation of that interface, whether Dagger generates it or not; this can help with testing.) You'll also need to remove the use of `@Singleton`, because Dagger would be very confused to have two separate components both claim to exist in singleton scope—one has to be created first, after all.

You haven't listed out the exact dependencies you're consuming out of NetComponent, so I don't have example changes I can show. However, for cases like this, I would recommend using subcomponents anyway; the bindings are more automatic, you likely won't benefit from the loose coupling you'd get from component dependencies, and you're closer to the design of [Dagger's official Android support package](https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html) so it's easier to migrate to that later.

Comment: I have `void inject(AuthenticationActivity authenticationActivity);` to provide `AppModule` and `NetModule` dependencies in each activity.

Comment: Do I need to add `ValidatorModule` in the `NetComponent.java` in modules ?

Comment: @Williams If you are pursuing the subcomponent solution, then no, you do not add ValidatorModule in NetComponent modules. Dagger sees that you've listed a Subcomponent on your Component and will inspect that Subcomponent for its list of modules. The reason you can't list `inject` in each Component is that there's no way to tell Dagger "just inject half of this class"; it's all or nothing, so instead I'm recommending that you make ValidationComponent aware of _all_ of the bindings AuthenticationActivity needs (delegating to NetComponent when necessary).

Comment: I am getting this error https://pastebin.com/1F6SWU9P and this is my `onCreate()`  https://pastebin.com/LFiGJ0Y9

Comment: That seems to be happening in your `Validator`, which you haven't shown us. As the details in this problem get to be more specific (and absent from your original question), I'm less sure that "The question is widely applicable to a large audience."

Comment: I have shown everything, Validator is a class of library. If you see my question there is `ValidatorModule.java` see there `@Provides
    com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator providesValidator() {
        return new com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator(activity);
    }` this is what `Validator` I have in an activity

Comment: I hope my last statement made more clear about `Validator` ?

Comment: @JeffBowman, sir, I'm delighted by all your answers you give for `dagger` specific questions and I learn a lot from them. Nevertheless, I couldn't find exact answer to the question which would dramatically vary from the answer I provided (which you eventually reasonably downvoted).

Comment: @azizbekian I wanted to write my own context, and I made sure to credit your answer. I only downvoted because of the terminology error you fixed, and because you hadn't mentioned removing the inject method from NetComponent (which is the root cause of the error). I hope that came through in the comments I left on your answer.

Comment: @JeffBowman Can you help me, it is not resolved. I tried your solution and hinted for `Validator` "Validator is a class of library. If you see my question there is `ValidatorModule.java` see there `@Provides com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator providesValidator() { return new com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator(activity); }` this is what `Validator` I have in an activity"

Comment: @Williams I'm afraid I don't think I have enough information to help you (and future readers) efficiently beyond what I've already posted.

Comment: I resolved it by changing `void inject(AuthenticationActivity activity);` instead of  `void inject(Activity activity);` in `ValidationComponent.java` I do not how it matters ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Williams you have to specify the invariant type of the injection site so that Dagger 2 knows to look for the `@Inject` annotations there. Jeff's already given you a lot of help, maybe you should accept his answer?

Comment: @DavidRawson Sure! I will. can you please help me how I can see my dependency graph ?

Comment: @Williams I'm afraid there is no tool for visualising the dependency graph (like their was for Guice). You'll have to draw it out on a piece of paper yourself

Comment: @DavidRawson Well. I am new in dagger2, not sure how it tries to build graph dependency.. lemme search

Comment: @JeffBowman Really great answer!! Thank you so much and difference between them made my concept strong too :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` you have following piece of code:

```
((AppApplication) getApplication()).getmNetComponent().inject(this);

ValidationComponent validationComponent = DaggerValidationComponent.builder()
        .validatorModule(getValidatorModule())
        .build();

validationComponent.inject(this);
```

And you have declared that you are willing to `@Inject` a `Validator` instance.

Hence when `getmNetComponent().inject(this)` is reached, Dagger will try to inject that dependency, but it cannot find in that component, because it will be provided from `ValidatorComponent` (which will be executed later).

This is a situation, when you have to make use of [subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html). Basically, your `ValidatorComponent` needs to see all dependencies provided by `NetworkComponent` and also add some of its own.

Following changes should be made:

**NetComponent.java**

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
    public interface NetComponent {
        void inject(AuthenticationActivity authenticationActivity);

        void inject(PaymentActivity paymentActivity);

        ValidatorComponent validatorComponent(ValidatorModule validatorModule);
    }
```

**ValidationComponent.java**

```
    @YourCustomScope
    @Subcomponent(modules = {ValidatorModule.class})
    public interface ValidationComponent {
        void inject(Activity activity);
    }
```

**AuthenticationActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((AppApplication) getApplication()).getmNetComponent()
                                           .validatorModule(new ValidatorModule(this))
                                           .inject();

    }
```

**YourCustomScope.java**

```
    @Scope
    @Documented
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface YourCustomScope {}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it did not work for me. What about `AppApplication.java`. Don't I need to do any change there ? see my question to check `AppApplication.java`

Comment: What does `it did not work for me` mean? What exact issue has arose?

Comment: I am getting same error logs which I pasted in question

Comment: This is not correct or sufficient; as long as NetComponent claims to be able to inject AuthenticationActivity, which has a Validator dependency, NetComponent will not be able to be generated.

Comment: As a side note, please look closer into the difference between component dependencies and subcomponents. You've described how to create a subcomponent, but you're calling it a component dependency.

Comment: @Williams I just finished typing out my answer; hopefully that helps describe what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using kotlin you have to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in your build.gradle file 
and alose use kapt instead of annotationProcessor in your dependencies

chage this :

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.22'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.22'
```

to this:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.22'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.22'
```