# Dagger 2 does not provide Retrofit API

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2

I try to call API with Retrofit and Dagger 2 and in my case the DataModel and it's module are injected fine, but not the module of API. I'm sure I miss something, but do not understand what. Here is my Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [SMModule::class, SMNetworkModule::class])
interface SMComponent {

fun inject(fragment: SMListFragment)
}
```

Modules:

```
@Module
class SMModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSMModel(): SMListDataModel {
        return SMListDataModel()
    }
}

@Module
object SMNetworkModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        val okHttpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        }
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpBuilder.build())
            .build()
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSMInterface(retrofit: Retrofit): SMInterface =
        retrofit.create(SMInterface::class.java)
}
```

DataModel:

```
class SMListDataModel @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var smApi: SMAPI

    override fun loadData(): DataResponse {
        return smApi.getData().blockingGet()
    }
}
```

my API:

```
@Singleton
class SMAPI @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var smInterface: SMInterface

    fun getData(): Single<DataResponse> {
        return smInterface.getData()
    }
}
```

and here I inject my Fragment and call DataModel:

```
@JvmField
@Inject
var dataModel: StocksListDataModel? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    DaggerSMComponent.create().inject(this)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val response = dataModel?.loadData()
}
```

and I get an error:

> UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property smApi has not been initialized

inside of my SMListDataModel.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889317/dagger2-is-not-generating-classes-in-android) and there I didn't see the explicit constructor for the API and it works for them. But not for me.

Comment: It just about understanding dagger. In my `generated` files I have `SMAPI_Factory implements Factory<SMAPI>` and my component includes both modules, but SMAPI is slitt `null` in my dataModel. If I need to call `SMAPI()`, what is the reason to use dagger?

Comment: `@Singleton
class SMAPI @Inject constructor(private val smInterface: SMInterface) {...}` / `class SMListDataModel @Inject constructor(private val smApi: SMAPI) {...}`

Comment: thanks a lot! It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works well. (provide Room & Retrofit).
i hope it's be useful

RemoteModule class :

```
@Module(includes = [AppModule::class])
class RemoteModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideArticleDatabase(application: App): RoomDataBase? {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        application.applicationContext,
        RoomDataBase::class.java,
        "fandogh"
    )
        .build()
}


@Provides
fun provideArticleDao(@Nullable articleDatabase: RoomDataBase): ILocalDataSource? {
    return articleDatabase.roomDao()
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun getApiInterface(retroFit: Retrofit): ApiService {
    return retroFit.create(ApiService::class.java)
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun getRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
 //  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun getOkHttpCleint(httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,  myAuthHeaderInterceptor: MyAuthHeaderInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
     return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    //  .addInterceptor {
    //   var request = it.request().newBuilder().addHeader("authorization", Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER).build()
//       return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
 //      }
        .addInterceptor(myAuthHeaderInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        .build()
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
fun getHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    return httpLoggingInterceptor
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun getAuthHeaderInterceptor(sharedPrefrences: SharedPreferences):  MyAuthHeaderInterceptor {
    return MyAuthHeaderInterceptor(sharedPrefrences)
}

}
```

ViewModelModule :

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {


@Binds
abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory // this needs to be only one for whole app (therefore marked as `@Singleton`)


@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
abstract fun loginViewModel(viewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(ActMainViewModel::class)
abstract fun mainActivityViewModel(viewModel: ActMainViewModel): ViewModel

}
```

FragmentBuilder:

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuilder {



@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun homeFragment(): HomeFragment?

}
```

ActivityBuilder :

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun loginActivity(): ActivityLogin?

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity?
}
```

AppModule :

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule {

@Binds
@Singleton
abstract fun application(app: App?): Application?
}
```

ActivityScope :

```
@Scope
@Retention(value = AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ActivityScope
```

FragmentScope :

```
@Scope
@Retention(value = AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class FragmentScope {
 }
```

AppComponent :

```
@Singleton
@ApplicationScope
@Component(
modules = [AppModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, RemoteModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class,
    FragmentBuilder::class, ViewModelModule::class]
)
 interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

fun inject(membersFragment: MembersFragment)

override fun inject(myApplication: App)

fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: App): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent


}
}
```

Application :

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

 var appComponent: AppComponent? = null

override fun applicationInjector(): AppComponent {
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    appComponent!!.inject(this)
    return appComponent!!
}
 }
```

and used in ViewModel :

```
class LoanViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

@Inject
lateinit var apiService: ApiService

  }
```